# postJson not returning values

Tags: jquery, json

I have two functions and the second one should work only on the success of the first one. The first function makes a postJson call and hence i wanted to write the second function on the success of first function only? i tried the following code but the variable is returning undefined.

```
    var serviceCall = $.postJSON('iwantdata.htm', {wowData:wowData, value:value}, function (data) {
    }
    serviceCall.success(function(){
    createForm();
    });
```

I am getting undefined for this serviceCall variable. Is there a problem with the postJson call or i need to change my approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$.postJSON()` method until you extended jQuery.

It should be:

```
$.post('iwantdata.htm', {wowData:wowData, value:value}, function(data) {
    //...
}, 'json');
```

Comment: I have extended jquery and I would have to use the aforesaid method only. Can there be something so that I can synchronise the json call so that it runs only if the service succeeds and returns a value/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is more readable:

```
$.post('iwantdata.htm', {wowData:wowData, value:value}, function (data) {        
    createForm();
}, 'JSON');
```

Comment: I am using it in the form that I have written above. I need a variable to get the success object similar to which is obtained for a getJson and which I have got earlier and used easily. If you can suggest something similar of that nature please do.